# F# nameof for record property

Tags: f#, nameof

I'm trying to use the new `nameof` feature in F# 5.0 preview. It works for `values` but not for record properties, e.g.:

```ml
type MyType { Id: int }
let name = nameof MyType.Id
```

This results in the error `FS0728   Field 'Id' is not static`

I tried doing:

```ml
let name = nameof<MyType.Id>
let name = nameof(MyType.Id)
let name = nameof Id
```

And neither fix the error. Is there a special way I'm supposed to do this or was `nameof` not fully implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [F# nameof operator not a first-class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002244/f-nameof-operator-not-a-first-class-function).

The short answer is:

```
let x = Unchecked.defaultof<MyType>
let name = nameof x.Id
```